Audio Tosofs shiuirm on the Daf
Is there a phone line where i can dial in and hear Tosfos on the Daf shiuirm?
Is there a website where i can download Tosfos on the Daf shiuirm?
I cant seem to find this anywhere

I find these free outlines very useful: https://dafyomi.co.il/section.php?gid=1&sid=13 Otherwise consider buying ArtScroll's new edition:https://www.artscroll.com/Categories/TOSAF.html

I would be very surprised if you it is possible to find any shiurim which deal only with Tosafos.
